# C# WPF Update UI Application freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

In C# we know there is multiple Background thread ... so like that can we create multiple UI thread?

and Multiple UI thread helps to update data in observation collection without freeez?

if No. what is the best way to get data from webservice and update to observation collection..

Code:-

```
Thread lthrThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
{
       string Data = DataFromServer()
       this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        UI freeze here for 5 -10 seconds
                    }));        
});
lthrThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
lthrThread.Start();
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. There's only one UI thread. What do you really want to ask?

Comment: hey sorry .. actually i want to Update UI after get data from server without freeze .... currently i am using Thread for server call and Inside Thread using Dispatcher but it freeze UI for 5-10 seconds

Comment: Just use `async/await`

Comment: @MickyD hey can you provide me sample async/await or reference i am new in this please ... i want to learn about async/await

Comment: Update code please look once

Answer (score 0):

UI thread is main thread.You cannot copy of it.If you call your data on ui thread,your application user interface will not respond until it ends.So,you need to create background thread or task that handles data call from webservices.When you get data from webservice pass it to the main thread (UI). You can use `Dispatcher` for it.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
 // Pass data to UI here.
}));
```

or you can use `async Task` which will be more convenient.

Comment: Can you give me example or reference of async Task /

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx this link will be enough for you.